# How do you listen to notifications from iTunes on a Mac (Using the NSDistributedNotificationCenter)

Tags: python, macos, notifications, pyobjc

Looking for help/tutorials/sample code of using python to listen to [distributed notifications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000396-2831) from applications on a mac. I know the [py-objc](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/) lib is the bridge between python and mac/cocoa classes, and the Foundation library can be used to add observers, but looking for examples or tutorials on how to use this to monitor iTunes.

Comment: Does iTunes actually post distributed notifications these days?

Comment: Yes it does.... under com.apple.iTunes.player, using notification watch i can see them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If anyone comes by to this question, i figured out how to listen, the code below works. However accessing attributes do not seem to work like standard python attribute access.

Update: you do not access attributes as you would in python i.e (.x), the code has been updated below, it now generates a dict called song_details.

Update3: Update to the code, now subclassing NSObject, removed adding the addObserver from the class. Will keep the code updated on [github](http://gist.github.com/260617), no more updates here.

```
import Foundation
from AppKit import *
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper

class GetSongs(NSObject):
    def getMySongs_(self, song):
        song_details = {}
        ui = song.userInfo()
        for x in ui:
            song_details[x] = ui.objectForKey_(x)
        print song_details

nc = Foundation.NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
GetSongs = GetSongs.new()
nc.addObserver_selector_name_object_(GetSongs, 'getMySongs:', 'com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo',None)

NSLog("Listening for new tunes....")
AppHelper.runConsoleEventLoop()
```

Answer (score 4):

The source code for GrowlTunes might give you some clues here. You'd have to translate from Objective-C to PyObjC, but eh, whatever. :)

[GrowlTurnesController.m](http://growl.info/hg/growl-development/file/4aa7c658ee1a/Extras/GrowlTunes/GrowlTunesController.m)
(Or grab the whole growl source tree and navigate to GrowlTunes so you can see it all in action.: [here's a link to the directions on how to get the source](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/growl-source-install.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help, managed to figure it out using pyobjc website &  apple web site.