# Volume changed notification in iTunes

Tags: cocoa, macos, itunes

I know how to get information about a current track in iTunes with Cocoa Scripting Bridge thanks to an answer to my following question:

[How to hook a listener to iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930771/how-to-hook-a-listener-to-itunes)

But I couldn't receive a notification in this way when volume changed.

Is there any way to hook a listener for volume?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You'll just have to poll.

Answer (score 1):

Try binding to the soundVolume property - not sure if updates will get observed.

Comment: It won't, because Scripting Bridge is implemented using Apple Script. It doesn't get any callbacks if a property changes in iTunes...