# AppleScript daemon to monitor iTunes playback info

Tags: scripting, applescript, itunes

Is it possible to write an AppleScript as a daemon to monitor or poll from iTunes the current playing song info such as artist name, song title, playback position, etc. ?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to get the info at the exact starting moment of the song.

If yes, where can I find the resources to learn how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it *is* possible to write a launch agent or daemon-like background app that uses AppleScript to get the currently playing iTunes song.

[Looking at this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631376/itunes-applescript-event), I see that whenever the state of iTunes changes, it sends out a systemwide notification event named "`com.apple.itunes.playerinfo`" [that you can register your app to listen for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845865/get-notification-using-nsdistributednotificationcenter-for-itunes-on-song-info-c).